# Bug when creating a class without using the new keyword

Tags: c++

So I have a node class. I add a single node to a std::vector if mouse is pressed. This is the way I did it the  first time.

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y)
    {
    };
    int x = 0; 
    int y = 0;
    Node* neighbours = nullptr;
};

std::vector<Node*> nodes;
//The following is in a while loop
if (GetMouse(0).bPressed) {
    Node node = Node(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize / 2));
    nodes.push_back(&node);
}
```

What I was hoping is that a node would be created and x, y position of that node would be set to mouse x and mouse y. Then the address of that node would be added to the vector.

That isn't quite what happens. After struggling for a bit, while printing all the x and y positions of nodes in the list, I noticed that they were all the same (position of the latest added node). I am struggling to see why this happens.

After searching google for a bit, I replaced the code with this and it works fine.

```
if (GetMouse(0).bPressed){
    Node* node = new Node(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize /2));
    nodes.push_back(node);
}
```

It works now and i just want to know why all the positions were same the first time.

Comment: No, that is *exactly* what’s happening. But the address to an object is useless after that object goes out of scope which, in your case, is happening immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is pushing a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope immediately after the push, destroying the node and leaving the vector with a dangling pointer, eg:

```cpp
if (GetMouse(0).bPressed)
{
    Node node = Node(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize / 2));
    nodes.push_back(&node);
} // <-- node is destroyed here!
```

Using `new` instead mitigates that issue, by allocating the `node` dynamically so it is not destroyed until you destroy it explicitly. Just make sure you actually `delete` the nodes when you are done using them, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<Node*> nodes;

...

if (GetMouse(0).bPressed)
{
    Node *node = new Node(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize / 2));
    nodes.push_back(node);
}

...

for(Node *node : nodes) {
    delete node;
}
nodes.clear();
```

Alternatively, use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` and let it manage the destructions for you, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes;

...

if (GetMouse(0).bPressed)
{
    auto node = std::make_unique<Node>(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize / 2));
    nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
}

...

nodes.clear();
```

Otherwise, change the `vector` to not hold pointers at all, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<Node> nodes; // <-- no *

...

if (GetMouse(0).bPressed)
{
    Node node(mouseX - (nodeSize / 2), mouseY - (nodeSize / 2));
    nodes.push_back(node); // <-- no &
}

...
```

Though, I suspect that last one will not suit your needs in the long run due to the `Node::neighbours` member.  So, stick with dynamic allocation, that is the typical use-case for a linked-list anyway.